# Fetch Data With CURL From Page in JSON In PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have Build A Code From Getting Algo Last Update Code Some Time Ago This is Working Perfect But Yesterday Night This Is Not Working I Have Tried Many To Solve This Problem But I'm Failed I can't Understand Where is The Problem

I'm Trying Here is My Code

```
        function curl($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        $uaa = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: $uaa");
        $exec=curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $exec;
        }
        $url = 'https://www.jwz.org/hacks/youtubedown';

        $data = curl($url);
        $rep = str_replace("' => '", "", $data);
        $date =  date('M Y');
        $explode = explode($date, $rep);
        $co = count($explode);
        $min = $co - 2;
        $act_explode = $explode[$min];
        $exp_algo = explode('base', $act_explode);
        $exp_algo_sts = $exp_algo[1];
        $replace_extra = substr($exp_algo_sts, 0, -7);
        $exp_sts = explode(' ', $replace_extra);
        $exp_algo_sts = $exp_sts[0];
        $exp_algo_algo = str_replace($exp_algo_sts,'',$replace_extra);
        $algo = substr($exp_algo_algo, 1);
        $final = '{"sts":'.$exp_algo_sts.',"algo":"'.$algo.'"}';
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        file_put_contents('algo-key.txt',$final);
        echo $final;
```

Output in Text File Format is 
{"sts":"17494","algo":"w45 w69 w2 r s1 r s1 r"}

How To I Solve This Problem

Comment: Permission issue ?

Comment: no bro not permission issue

Comment: checked answer ?

Answer (score 0):

your `$exp_algo` has only one element `$exp_algo[0]` but you are trying to access an element which doesn't exist. 
`$exp_algo[1]`.
This causes undefined offset exception.
Check for the change in the data

Check the below code
In there the array has been isolated using the function name

```
public function test2(){
    function curl($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        $uaa = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: $uaa");
        $exec=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $exec;
    }
    $url = 'https://www.jwz.org/hacks/youtubedown';

    $data = curl($url);


    $rep = str_replace("' => '", "", $data);

    $finalString = $this->get_string_between($rep,"my %ciphers = (",");");

    $date =  date('M Y');
    $explode = explode($date, $finalString);
    //print_r($explode);exit;
    $co = count($explode);
    $min = $co - 2;
    $act_explode = $explode[$min];
   // print_r($act_explode);exit;
    $exp_algo = explode('base', $act_explode);

    $exp_algo_sts = $exp_algo[1];
    $replace_extra = substr($exp_algo_sts, 0, -7);
    $exp_sts = explode(' ', $replace_extra);
    $exp_algo_sts = $exp_sts[0];
    $exp_algo_algo = str_replace($exp_algo_sts,'',$replace_extra);
    $algo = substr($exp_algo_algo, 1);
    $final = '{"sts":'.$exp_algo_sts.',"algo":"'.$algo.'"}';
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    file_put_contents('algo-key.txt',$final);
    echo $final;


}

private  function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

Comment: any other way to retrive this last code from main url `'player-vflJtN5rw/en_US/base' => '17494 w45 w69 w2 r s1 r s1 r',# 24 Nov 2017`

Comment: check the code in the answer. this will print {"sts":17494,"algo":"w45 w69 w2 r s1 r s1 r"}

Comment: `get_string_between`? seriously, take some time to study [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) - it's so much more powerful ^^